# EF Core migration on app start fails with "login failed" but works via package manager console

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

We have multiple applications that use EF Core Code First. Earlier, the databases were created automatically on my local Sql Server 2019 when I first debugged an application locally from Visual Studio 2022. Now that stopped working for some reason and I get the following error message:

> Cannot open database "XX" requested by the login. The login failed.
> Login failed for user 'Domain\user'.

An example connection string is (I also tried adding Trusted_Connection=True; at the end, doesn't change anything):

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=XX;Integrated Security=true
```

When I use the package manager console "Update-Database" command, the databases are created as expected and all migrations are executed.

Also, I can create databases with the same user 'Domain\user' via SQL Server Management Studio.

One more thing that I noticed is that I get a different error message if I first create an empty database via SSMS and then start the application. In this case no migrations are performed and the error message is (where Events is some table the application uses):

```
'Invalid object name 'Events'.'
```

Comment: Do these EF Core apps happen to be web apps? When they're running in the web server they'll be executing in a different account context.

Comment: Yes they are. But they were before, so that doesn't explain why it stopped working?